# Why GoConvey Tests fail with error code 0?

Tags: testing, go, continuous-integration, tdd, goconvey

I need to run my GoConvey tests as part of my build
how do i make sure `go test` exits with error exit code (not 0)?

Comment: GoConvey supports Go's native testing package. Neither the web UI nor the DSL are required; you can use either one independently.

Comment: @Bert Verhees i run go test, see a failing test but get exit code 0...

Comment: `go test` should exit with code 1 on test failures, [see this](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/testing/testing.go#L1040-L1046), and that value is used [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/go_test.go#L212-L218). For various initialisation errors it seems to use exit code 2. It would be helpful if you could provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found the bug:

I have TestMain in my code that runs before the tests:

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    log.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard) // Disable logs.
    m.Run()
}
```

`m.Run` should be wrapped with `os.Exit` so it can be used with error status codes:

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    log.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard) // Disable logs.
    os.Exit(m.Run())
}
```

that fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can run goconvey as a normal test, you can test this very simply by writing a small test which gives a predictable result, like this

```
package c

import (
    "testing"
    . "github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/convey"
)

func TestConvey(t *testing.T){
    Convey("TestConvey", t, func() {
        So(false, ShouldBeTrue)
    })
}
```

This should be the result
    xxx 14:44:03 ~/GO/src/c/c > go test
    x
    Failures:

```
* /home/xxx/GO/src/c/c/a_test.go 
Line 10:
Expected: true
Actual:   false


1 total assertion

--- FAIL: TestConvey (0.00s)
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    c/c     0.006s
```

Comment: i ran your example and got exit code 0 for that failing test

Comment: No, you did not run my example, you wrapped it in some other code and then ran it. That is a completely other story, which caused me and you headaches. Don't do that again.